# How does Weka calculate the output predictions in J48 and other classifier?

Tags: weka

I have used the output predictions of J48 classifier in Weka and got the results with predictions (probability). As I need to use these predictions number in my research, I need to know how the weka calculates these numbers? What is the formula? Is it specified for each classifier?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **Jan Eglinger** answer.

The J48 classifier is Weka's implementation of the infamous C4.5 decision tree classifier, which is a classification algorithm based on ID3 that classifies using information entropy.

The training data is a set `S = {s_1, s_2, ...}` of already classified samples. Each sample  s_i consists of a p-dimensional vector `(x_{1,i}, x_{2,i}, ...,x_{p,i})` , where the  `x_j`  represent attribute values or features of the sample, as well as the class in which  `s_i`  falls.

At each node of the tree, C4.5 chooses the attribute of the data that most effectively splits its set of samples into subsets enriched in one class or the other. The splitting criterion is the normalized information gain (difference in entropy). The attribute with the highest normalized information gain is chosen to make the decision. The C4.5 algorithm then recurs on the smaller sublists.

This algorithm has a few base cases.

1. All the samples in the list belong to the same class. When this
   happens, it simply creates a leaf node for the decision tree saying
   to choose that class.
2. None of the features provide any information gain. In this case,
   C4.5 creates a decision node higher up the tree using the expected
   value of the class.
3. Instance of previously-unseen class encountered. Again, C4.5 creates
   a decision node higher up the tree using the expected value.

You can find the information Gain and entropy in the Weka Api package. For that you need to start dubbing the java weka api and go through each step.

In general, if you don't worry about how algorithm works internally using high level mathematics. Try to calculate InformationGain and entropy and explain them in your research apart from decision trees, you have methods for both of these to calculate their value.

Comment: Thanks Jan Eglinger and Max Rattan for your kind information. But, I think I did not ask my question clearly. Actually, I just want to know more about the probability output calculated by the weka in csv format. As you know, in the output of Weka classification, we can get also some prediction (certainty) number between 0 and 1 for each instance. I am searching to find the formula or method which is used by the weka to calculate these numbers. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> What is the formula?

Weka's J48 classifier is an implementation of the [C4.5 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm).

> I need to know how the weka calculates these numbers?

You can find implementation details in [`J48.java`](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.java) and in the [`weka.classifiers.trees.j48` package](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/tree/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/trees/j48).